# Why does Golden Sparrow always use "she" instead of "I" or "My"?

Tags: character, the-forbidden-kingdom

In *The Forbidden Kingdom (2008)*, Golden Sparrow(Liu Yifei) always speaks weird English, She address herself as "she" instead of "I" or "My".

For Example: My Name is Richard.

But in her words; she says: She name is Golden Sparrow.

Comment: Could please stop editing this question, it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a figure of speech, sometimes when people speak, they refer themselves in third person perspective. Could be various reasons. In some cultures, people usually address themselves in third person perspective because they believe that addressing themselves in first person is not good.

This incident is called Illeism (from Latin ille meaning "he, that") which is the act of referring to oneself in the third person instead of first person.

Illeism is sometimes used in literature as a stylistic device. In real life usage, illeism can reflect a number of different stylistic intentions or involuntary circumstances.

In this matter, Sparrow refers herself in third person because she needs  to give the herself lofty airs, to puff herself up or illustrate her egoism.